# Что такое sudo access?

Tags: sudo

Что такое sudo access? Как дать этот sudo access на конкретного пользователя, и чем это собственно опасно?

> it's important to understand how to do this, because you don't want to
> give everyone sudo access, and you don't want to run around in your
> computer as ROOT because you could destroy something important on
> accident.

Comment: Можно почитать man. Но если вам надо дать права рута кому-то, то лучше делать это, редактируя `sudoers` с помощью `visudo`

Comment: а как это сделать? яи в чем разница между "даванием" рут прав через терминал, и через системные настройки

Comment: Вот тут всё написано https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sudo. Не знаю, что такое "системные настройки". Если это какой-то GUI, то разница в уровне абстракции, итог должен быть одинаковый

Comment: https://youtu.be/9JOS6RQNpEM    Так можно дать рут права, или лучше через терминал?

Comment: Не советую настраивать систему по ютуб-видосам, лучше читать документацию к вашему дистрибутиву

Comment: а в чем разница между sudo и root?

Comment: В первом предложении ссылки, которую я скинул, дано определение sudo, использующее root. В этой же вики можете найти статью про root

Comment: а, боже. Перечитал еще раз и доперло. Спасибо вам,  добрые люди

Comment: так как мне это sudo дать на конкретного пользователя?

Comment: sudo - это команда, которая позволяет обычному пользователю временно стать рутом. Предоставление доступа к команде sudo прописывается в файле sudoers, документации про него в интернете навалом и выше в комментах уже ссылку дали

Answer (score 1):

root - это суперпользователь, который логинится и далее каждая команда в сессии такого пользователя выполняется с правами суперпользователя. В консоли вместо $ перед курсором появляется знак #, напоминающий вам о том, что вы можете случайно очень мощно накосячить, причем не в папке своего пользователя, а во всей файловой системе.

sudo - это команда, расшифровка "superuser do", то есть, исполнение одной команды, программы, скрипта с правами суперпользователя. Эта функция снижает риск обрушения системы, так как вы каждый раз пишете sudo, прежде чем сделать что-либо с правами суперпользователя, и благодаря этому вы помните, что команды выполняются с такими правами.

Список sudoers - это список пользователей, которым администратор позволяет вызывать sudo. При выполнении sudo вы вводите пароль, и ваши действия логируются.

Если машина лично ваша, вы будете в sudoers уже после установки ОС.